How could i control request Retries in go-micro+grpc?
I am trying to create a subject base on go-mciro(v4) and grpc. But i try to call  a rpc server function in my api-gateway which can be as rpc client. The problem occured that server function was called many times not only one which i expect.
In my server function detail, it will try to send a http post request to another service which maybe consume some time.
I try to replace the http request in my server function like follow:
    messageRequest := aiproxy.ConversationMessageRequest{
        Content:          strings.Join(req.Content, "|"),
        ConversationMode: req.ConversationMode,
        ConversationID:   req.ConversionId,
    }

    messageResp, err := aiproxy.GetMessageFromLLM(&messageRequest)
    if err != nil || len(messageResp.Content) == 0 {
        iLogger.LogrusObj.Error("err from ai:", err)
        resp.Code = statuscode.FailedRequestAI
        return nil
    }

replace to
messageResp := aiproxy.ConversationMessageResponse{
        Content:    []string{"hello", "world", "!"},
        TokenUsage: 3,
    }


if can be work!
so i guess thers could have some retry mechanism especially in case of response timeout，actually it does. So i do some settings in go-mciro client, like:
func WithTimeout(d time.Duration) client.CallOption {
    return func(o *client.CallOptions) {
        o.RequestTimeout = d
        o.Retries = 0
    }
}

rpcResp1, err := service.CreateTitle(ctx, &titleReq, WithTimeout(time.Second*70))

but still cant work
